# Please start writing out the incomplete tag wiki excerpts

Tags: discussion

We have ~24 [tags](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/tags) on the main site without any tag excerpts, at the time of writing this post. It would be really helpful if the community members gradually start writing out the tag excerpts for the incomplete ones. See: [What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts). Also, it is a request that whenever you create a new tag, at least try to write the tag excerpt by yourself, so that others don't have to put in the effort on your behalf. Moreover, members with <4000 reputation points get +2 points for each accepted excerpt suggestion, so apparently, it is a fair use of your time ;)! If you have any confusion about what to write in any particular tag's excerpt, feel free to drop a message in the [main chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74398/the-classical-channel) room. Thank you.

Comment: I have added one for graph-states. Apologies for the delay

Comment: Just added basic info for quantum networks. Looks like only [energy-relaxtion](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/tags/energy-relaxation/info) & [state injection](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state-injection) left! (Should state-injection be removed? 0 questions currently..)